# 'universal' option is not working in wheels

Tags: python, pip, cython, setuptools, python-wheel

i'm trying to make a universal wheel for a extension python package from my Linux machine in order to install it easily on my windows.

my setup.py is

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy.distutils.misc_util
import setuptools


with open('README.md', 'r') as f:
    readme = f.read()

with open('LICENSE', 'r') as f:
    license = f.read()

with open('VERSION', 'r') as f:
    version = f.read()

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'pylbfgs',
        sources=['pylbfgs.c'],
        libraries=['lbfgs'],
        library_dirs=['/usr/local/lib'],
        include_dirs=['/usr/local/include'] + (
            numpy.distutils.misc_util.get_numpy_include_dirs()
        ),
        runtime_library_dirs=['/usr/local/lib'],
        ),
    ]

setup(
    name='PyLBFGS',
    version=version,
    author='Robert Taylor',
    author_email='rtaylor@pyrunner.com',
    url='https://bitbucket.org/rtaylor/pylbfgs',
    description=(
        'PyLBFGS is a Python 3 wrapper of the libLBFGS '
        'library written by Naoaki Okazaki.'
        ),
    long_description=readme,
    license=license,
    install_requires=['numpy'],
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Programming Language :: C',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering',
        'Topic :: Software Development',
        ],
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    options={"bdist_wheel": {"universal": True}}

)
```

my setup.cfg:

```
[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1
```

and I'm running  `python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal`. actually I'm using every 3 options that can be used for making universal wheel but sill my output is `PyLBFGS-0.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl`

any idea where is the problem?

I'm using:
-Ubuntu Impish
-python 3.9
-Cython 0.29.26
-setuptools 60.2.0

and here is the project:
https://bitbucket.org/rtaylor/pylbfgs/src/master/

Comment: Universal means python2 and python3 and not Linux, windows and what not. You can cross compile for windows, but usually one would use windows to create windows wheel.

Comment: `ext_modules` prevent wheels to be universal. With Extensions you need to build your wheels for every platform you can.